# How to prevent part of HTML text from being copied when copying adjacent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a [JavaScript widget](https://github.com/matteoferla/PrettyFastaJS) which adds line numbers and one thing I cannot figure out is preventing the numbers from being copied when one copies the text. I want people to be able to copy the sequences around the numbers, but not the numbers.
[Here is an example of the script's results](http://rawgit.com/matteoferla/PrettyFastaJS/master/demo.html).

Basically:

```html
<span>useful stuff to be copied </span>
<span style="some-mysterious-setting: True;"> gloss to be discarded in selection </span>
<span> useful stuff to be copied</span>
```

The numbers are implemented as a separate span elements and not as a table or anything that fancy. I tried `user-select: none;` and its variants in CSS, but that means it does not get highlighted, but it copies nevertheless the numbering.

Comment: Do you output it in the exact way like in the example or like an typical editor? Like each line a number?

Comment: Oh, well it's actually your code.

Comment: I brought about the changes on GitHub file. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you don't need Javascript for this.

The solution is to use a pseudo element and not actually put the number in your element.

```
<span class="line-number" data-line-number="1"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.line-number::before {
  content: attr(data-line-number);
}
```

```css
td:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
td:nth-of-type(1)::before {
  content: attr(data-line-number);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-line-number="1"></td>
    <td>Test row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-line-number="2"></td>
    <td>Test row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-line-number="3"></td>
    <td>Test row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-line-number="4"></td>
    <td>Test row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also I would recommend using a table as in my snippet example. Not necessary but schematically and performance wise makes sense.

Comment: I love CSS only solutions, so this one will get my like! Didn't know you can access to the data attr with CSS. Is it even possible to get other non-data attributes with `attr()` ? You also have an point inside the class name `class=".line-number"`

Comment: @CagatayUlubay Yes `attr(X)` works with any attribute but it returns only a string not an integer/etc. [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Comment: I did not want to go for table as I did not constrain the blocks of text to fall in specify lines (in reality I am dealing with line numbering but I am splitting the DNA/protein sequence into blocks add adding numbers). Also related to tables I did have problems with the monospaced font not being monospaced when it came to hyphenation (&ndash; fixed it). I'll look into tables as it would prevent both issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `counter` too to get the result you want, if you have a large amount of data you are no longer in need to specify the line number.

CSS

```
table
{
    counter-reset: line;
    counter-increment: line;
}

td:nth-of-type(1)::before {
  counter-increment: line+10;
  content: counter(line) " ";
}

td:nth-of-type(1)
{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Row 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen this answer before selecting the answer.
But I'll definitely look into Counter as it could be handy here. Thanks.

Comment: It's great for most uses but I don't think there's a way to make it 4 digits so that it starts `0011` instead of `11`.

Comment: @Alejalapeno there is no way to do it with counter, your answer will be better for that case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work :

Javascript :

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("myElement");
elem.unselectable = "on";
```

Html :

```
<span>useful stuff to be copied </span>
<span class="myElement"> gloss to be discarded in selection </span>
<span> useful stuff to be copied</span>
```

Comment: The problem is, if you have text infront and at the end of the text and you copy it, you still get the middle, unselectable portion in your clipboard

Comment: yea i checked that. Unfortunately it doesnt work for splitted text but does work for whole text though!